# Count and then Concatenate in oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to Count 2 column values and the Concatenate those values by adding another column. I have written the following query:

```sql
select  IDS, count (EMP_FLAG) as EMP_COUNT, count (STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_COUNT
,CONCAT('EMP_COUNT' , 'STUDENT_COUNT') as TOTAL
```

But I cannot get the desired result.

[My Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcxT.png)

The result I am looking is

| ID | EMP COUNT | STU_COUNT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2/2 |

How I can achieve above result by Concatenating 2 count fields values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COUNT` statements in the the concatenation:

```sql
select IDS,
       count(EMP_FLAG) as EMP_COUNT,
       count(STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_COUNT,
       count(EMP_FLAG) || '/' || count(STUDENT_FLAG) AS total
```

*Note: `CONCAT` only accepts two arguments in Oracle so you would need `CONCAT(count(EMP_FLAG), CONCAT('/', count(STUDENT_FLAG)))` if you did want to use it. It is simpler just to use the string concatenation `||` operator.*

---

If you did want to use the aliases from the previous columns then you would need to use an inline view:

```sql
SELECT ids,
       emp_count,
       student_count,
       emp_count || '/' || student_count AS total
FROM   (
  select IDS,
         count(EMP_FLAG) as EMP_COUNT,
         count(STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_COUNT
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY ids
);
```

Comment: I am getting error -                                                                                                              
 ORA-00904: "STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT": invalid identifier                                                              I used following query as suggested-                                                                               select IDS,
 count (EMP_FLAG) as EMP_FLAG_COUNT,
count (STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT'
count(EMP_FLAG_COUNT) || count(STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT) AS total

Comment: @user23008854 That is not the same as I wrote in the answer. You cannot use the aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in another part of that same `SELECT` clause. You want: `select IDS, count (EMP_FLAG) as EMP_FLAG_COUNT, count (STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT, count(EMP_FLAG) || count(STUDENT_FLAG) AS total` (but you probably also want to include `|| '/'` in the concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

The query suggested by MT0 works but the data in the database  looks like this-

| REGNUMBER | STUDENT FLAG | EMP_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Y | N |
| ABC | N | Y |

So in the result I am getting :

| ID | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2/2 |

In total, I am getting  **2/2** instead of **1/1**

I have the query something like this but obviously it is not working:

```sql
SELECT
STUDENT.IDS,
STUDENT.STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT || '/' || EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_FLAG_COUNT AS total
FROM   
(
select REGNUMBER as IDS , count (STUDENT_FLAG) as STUDENT_FLAG_COUNT
FROM Table Name
where STUDENT_FLAG = 'Y'
group by REGNUMBER
)as STUDENT

INNER JOIN
(
select REGNUMBER  as IDS , count (EMPLOYEE_FLAG) as EMPLOYEE_FLAG_COUNT
FROM Table Name
where EMPLOYEE_FLAG = 'Y'
group by REGNUMBER
)as EMPLOYEE
on STUDENT.REGNUMBER = EMPLOYEE.REGNUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

@user23008854 Please correct the syntax error in your query to get the expected output:

1. count (EMPLOYEE_FLAG) as EMPLOYEE_FLAG_COUNT -- There is no EMPLOYEE_FLAG column in your table.
2. STUDENT.REGNUMBER = EMPLOYEE.REGNUMBER -- You have renamed the columns in inner query as  IDS so JOIN should consider this as the column name.
3. )as STUDENT )as EMPLOYEE -- Oracle does not like use the AS keyword to alias a subquery so you can take out AS keyword.

> ```
>  SELECT student.ids, student.student_flag_count || '/' || employee.employee_flag_count AS total FROM
>     (SELECT regnumber AS ids , COUNT (student_flag) AS student_flag_count 
>      FROM Table Name 
>      WHERE student_flag = 'Y' 
>     GROUP BY regnumber )  student
>     INNER JOIN 
>     ( SELECT regnumber AS ids , COUNT (emp_flag) AS employee_flag_count 
>       FROM Table Name
>       WHERE emp_flag = 'Y' 
>       GROUP BY regnumber )  employee  ON student.ids = employee.ids;
> ```